# How can I get confidence metrics from dateutil parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm using [datefinder](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder), which extracts possible date / time strings from a piece of text, then puts those strings through `dateutil.parser.parse()` to yield `datetime`s.

In a key use case, I have multiple resulting `datetime`s which probably correspond to the **same** date. I'd like to post process (how is not the subject here) to improve accuracy in the parsed dates.

**To do that, I need to get an indication of confidence in the parsed values.**

In a perfect world I'd be able to do:

```
dt, confidence = dateutil.parser.parse_with_confidence('12/12/2017')
print(confidence)
>> {'year': 1, 'month': 0.5, 'day': 0.5, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'seconds': 0, 'tz': 0}

dt, confidence = dateutil.parser.parse_with_confidence('12/Dec/2017')
print(confidence)
>> {'year': 1, 'month': 1, 'day': 1, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'seconds': 0, 'tz': 0}
```

Which would allow me to choose the second one, having a greater confidence in its month and day values.

**Partial workaround:**
I can call `dateutil` twice, with a totally different `default` date...

```
dt_a = dateutil.parser.parse('Dec2017', default=datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
>> 2017-12-01 00:00:00
dt_b = dateutil.parser.parse('Dec2017', default=datetime(2018, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1))
>> 2017-12-02 01:01:01
```

...then evaluate which values were assigned by the parser and which defaulted.

This is some way to achieving what I need, as it lets me choose between dates generated from (say) strings `'dec2017'` and `'11dec2017'` (where one contains more information than the other).

But, it's crude parsing twice, and it's actively misleading since in the above case, the latter has more information, but contains ambiguity.

Is there a module out there to do this? Or am I facing modifying `dateutils`?

Comment: There is no such notion of confidence, and this is a harder problem than you might think

Comment: Pretty sure those `default` arguments are wrong, too.

Comment: Fixed the defaults. @Paul there must be a notion of confidence - if I parse '11/12/2017' then I'm approx. 50% confident that the result is correct. Perhaps you could elaborate on some of the pitfalls you envisage?

Comment: No intermediate representation exists in the parser that keeps track of these things, and doing so would be somewhat difficult the way it is currently written. It's not like the tokens are parsed out and then assigned a probability.

Comment: Your notion of confidence is interesting but somewhat incomplete. There's no real way to *use* the fractional confidences because you don't know what the alternative ways to parse those tokens is, or even what they were to start with.